# Convert serialized protobuf output to python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, protocol-buffers

Given, a serialized protobuf (protocol buffer) output in the string format. I want to convert it to a python dictionary.

Suppose, this is the serialized protobuf, given as a python string:

```
person {
  info {
    name: John
    age: 20
    website: "https://mywebsite.com"
    eligible: True
  }
}
```

I want to convert the above python string to a python dictionary `data`, given as:

```py
data = {
  "person": {
    "info": {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 20,
      "website": "https://mywebsite.com",
      "eligible": True,
    }
  }
}
```

I can write a python script to do the conversion, as follows:

- Append commas on every line not ending with curly brackets.
- Add an extra colon before the opening curly bracket.
- Surround every individual key and value pair with quotes.
- Finally, use the `json.loads()` method to convert it to a Python dictionary.

I wonder whether this conversion can be achieved using a simpler or a standard method, already available in protocol buffers. So, apart from the manual scripting using the steps I mentioned above, is there a better or a standard method available to convert the serialized protobuf output to a python dictionary?

Comment: I've not tried this but you should be able to convert a message to a dictionary directly or through JSON. See `MessageToDict`: https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html

Comment: @DazWilkin I tried it, but it didn't work. The possible reason for not working is that in the `MessageToJson(message, ...)`, the `message` parameter is `The protocol buffer message instance to serialize.`, so it's an instance of the protocol buffer. I need conversion from a plain string to JSON, not from a protocol buffer object.

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem. This would be a better approach but evidently you don't the Protobuf message and you don't have the proto so you can't `ParseFromString` either. You have a binary string not a purely human-readable string and so you should take care converting it differently to JSON. See: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding

Comment: Have you found an answer to this problem?

Comment: @RKO No, didn't find a straightforward solution. One way is to use regex for doing the conversion, a better and standard way might be to add some functionality in the service returning the protobuf to also return a JSON upon passing some flag. E.g: pass -json flag to get the json output, else the protobuf output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `proto`'s `Message` class.

```
In [6]: import proto

In [7]: curr
Out[7]:
campaign {
  resource_name: "customers/1234/campaigns/5678"
  id: 9876
  name: "testing 1, 2, 3"
  advertising_channel_type: SEARCH
}
landing_page_view {
  resource_name: "customers/1234/landingPageViews/1234567890"
  unexpanded_final_url: "https://www.example.com/"
}

In [8]: proto.Message.to_dict(
   ...:     curr,
   ...:     use_integers_for_enums=False,
   ...:     including_default_value_fields=False,
   ...:     preserving_proto_field_name=True
   ...: )
Out[8]:
{'campaign': {'resource_name': 'customers/1234/campaigns/5678',
  'advertising_channel_type': 'SEARCH',
  'name': 'testing 1, 2, 3',
  'id': '9876'},
 'landing_page_view': {'resource_name': 'customers/1234/landingPageViews/1234567890',
  'unexpanded_final_url': 'https://www.example.com/'}}
```

Note that in `to_dict`, all kwargs default to `True`.

There's also a `to_json` method if you just want to immediately serialise the message without having to use `json.dumps`.

A caveat that's also worth noting is the `proto` package's [recent memory leaks](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/9917). The thread says that a fix has been issued but my experience when using it on larger datasets suggested otherwise . Just because something works locally, doesn't mean that the container you deploy it to can handle the same load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google package [`MessageToDict`](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html#google.protobuf.json_format.MessageToDict) function to covert proto3 message to python dict.

The relevant arguments are:

> ```txt
> use_integers_for_enums: If true, print integers instead of enum names.
> descriptor_pool: A Descriptor Pool for resolving types. If None use the
>         default.
> preserving_proto_field_name: If True, use the original proto field
>         names as defined in the .proto file. If False, convert the field
>         names to lowerCamelCase.
> including_default_value_fields: If True, singular primitive fields,
>         repeated fields, and map fields will always be serialized.  If
>         False, only serialize non-empty fields.  Singular message fields
>         and oneof fields are not affected by this option.
> ```

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
import test_pb2

python_dict = MessageToDict(
    message,
    preserving_proto_field_name=True,
    including_default_value_fields=True,
    descriptor_pool=test_pb2.test_output)["output_list"]
```

where my proto3 file has `test_output` as output from module.

Comment: This was already suggested in the original question comments, which OP said wouldn't work because "_I need conversion from a plain string to JSON, not from a protocol buffer object._"